# Return to normal execution after debugging a part of code

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea

When I debug a program using IntelliJ' debugger, how can I return to the normal execution of the program after debugging a part of the code ?

- I start a program, test it.
- When the debugger find breakpoints, it starts the step by step debugging of the program.
- I do my stuff and my checks, nothing goes wrong.
- I want to exit step by step debugging and go back to a fluid execution of the program (without having to press a button for all actions) until the debugger find a new breakpoint.

How can I do that and exit the step by step debugging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the "Resume Program" button, which looks like a green triangle (a "play" button"), or the <kbd>F9</kbd> shortcut.

See, e.g., this screenshot from a debugging session I started (mouse cursor and the hovering tooltip show the button's location):

[image]

Note: The screenshot was taken in IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4 so the exact layout may differ according to your specific version, but the same behavior, buttons and shortcuts have existed in IntelliJ for years now.